# Set checkbox value throw attribute boolean value

Tags: php, jquery, html, checkbox

I would like to set checkbox value with some attribute I put with PHP.

It seems weird but it's quite simple look, here is my PHP :

```
<input type="checkbox" val="'.$key->mes.'" class="mes"/>
```

My idea : check the checkbox when the val is 1, uncheck when it's 0

I try to figure this out with Jquery like this :

```
$('input:checkbox [val=1]').prop('checked', true);
```

But it doesn't work... Any tips?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're working in PHP already, how about this:

```
"<input type='checkbox' val='". $key->mes . "'" . $key->mes > 0 ? "checked='checked'" : "" .  "/>"
```

Then you don't need to do stuff client side...

Comment: I tested your code, there is some syntax mistake no ? I'm not really into PHP, what is the function you used?

Answer (score 3):

you should use `value` and not `val` attribute

```
<input type="checkbox" value="1" />
```

and

```
$('input:checkbox[value="1"]').prop('checked', 'checked');
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kabY3/

Comment: Chris Sobolewski has the right answer (below). <input type="checkbox" value="1" /> does not work. Should be: <input type="checkbox" checked />

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know you should not use `.prop('checked',true);` only calling `.prop("checked")` should be enough. source: jquery.com

> $(elem).prop("checked")   true (Boolean) Will change with checkbox
>   state

I've read that using `.prop("checked",false)` for instance is bad and you should go with `.removeProp()`

Have a look at the .prop documentation:

- http://api.jquery.com/prop/

But there should be a way php to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

i think is more easy doing it in php:

```
<?php
$ch="";
if($key->mes==1) $ch=' checked="checked"';
echo '<input type="checkbox" val="'.$key->mes.'" class="mes"'.$ch.'/> '
?>
```

if you want it in jquery try what @EvilP has suggest.

Answer (score 0):

As long as your `DOM` element properly reads `<input type="checkbox" val="1" class="mes">` using your favorite developer tools, I would just do `$('input[val=1]').prop('checked', true);`

Here is a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/remibreton/u96pc/